# RxAndroid `Observable...subscribe` highlighted in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, rx-android

I'm using RxAndroid to marshal a string from a background thread into the main thread, and do something with that string on that main thread:

```
String stringFromDatabase = readFromDatabase();

Observable.just(stringFromDatabase)
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe(new Consumer<String>() {
        @Override
        public void accept(String string) throws Exception {
            webViewFragment.onInjectMessage(string, null);
        }
    });
```

Android Studio is highlighting the entire `Observable.just...` command chain in yellow, telling me that "*The result of subscribe is not used*", when I hover on it.

If I add `.dispose()` to the end of the chain, the highlighting disappears, but the `webViewFragment.onInjectMessage(string, null);` code is no longer executed.

I noticed that I can remove the highlighting by adding a `@SuppressLint("CheckResult")` annotation to the entire method.

Is this something like a warning which can be safely ignored, or am I creating some kind of a memory leak or other problem here? Is this a bad practice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to dispose it to avoid memory leak. Try to dispose inside `onDestroy`

```
Disposable disposable;

String stringFromDatabase = readFromDatabase();
disposable = Observable.just(stringFromDatabase)
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe(new Consumer<String>() {
            @Override
            public void accept(String string) {
                webViewFragment.onInjectMessage(string, null);
            }
        });

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    disposable.dispose();
}
```

Comment: You reminded me that it's possible to call dispose from within the subscriber. I think there is a special subscriber or something which allows doing this, which would be ideal, because I would then dispose after calling `webViewFragment.onInjectMessage(string, null);`. Hmm, need to look through some code of another project...

Comment: It's the `Observer<String>` which has the `onSubscribe` which passes the disposable, I think it was that.

Comment: @DanielF Yes, That is :)

Comment: Are you sure that not disposing creates a memory leak? I've done some for-loop benchmarking with Android Studio's Profile visible, and also with StrictMode on, and nothing seemed to indicate that anything was getting leaked. In addition to that an example on GitHub https://github.com/amitshekhariitbhu/RxJava2-Android-Samples/blob/c91b115648b9ff08b9d6441a03c4d2f511ca09de/app/src/main/java/com/rxjava2/android/samples/ui/operators/SingleObserverExampleActivity.java#L50-L69 also did not explicitly call dispose.

Comment: I think it only creates a memory leak if you assign the disposable to a variable.