# Does a SingleObserver need to be disposed? If so, where?

Tags: android, memory-leaks, rx-java2, rx-android, reactivex

I have the following piece of code

```
Single.just(settings.toString())
  .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
  .subscribe(new SingleObserver<String>() {
    private Disposable disposable;
    @Override public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {
        this.disposable = d;
    }
    @Override public void onSuccess(String s) {
        webViewFragment.onInjectMessage(s, null);
        this.disposable.dispose();
    }
    @Override public void onError(Throwable e) {
        this.disposable.dispose();
    }
});
```

I am in a background thread and need to inject a string into a WebView, which can only be done on the main thread, which is why i'm calling `.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()`

Yet when I read through the sample code of [`SingleObserver` on GitHub](https://github.com/amitshekhariitbhu/RxJava2-Android-Samples/blob/c91b115648b9ff08b9d6441a03c4d2f511ca09de/app/src/main/java/com/rxjava2/android/samples/ui/operators/SingleObserverExampleActivity.java#L50-L69), I see the following:

```
return new SingleObserver<String>() {
    @Override public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {
        Log.d(TAG, " onSubscribe : " + d.isDisposed());
    }
    @Override public void onSuccess(String value) {
        textView.append(" onNext : value : " + value);
        textView.append(AppConstant.LINE_SEPARATOR);
        Log.d(TAG, " onNext value : " + value);
    }
    @Override public void onError(Throwable e) {
        textView.append(" onError : " + e.getMessage());
        textView.append(AppConstant.LINE_SEPARATOR);
        Log.d(TAG, " onError : " + e.getMessage());
    }
};
```

They are not disposing `SingleObserver`.

Is it required for me to call `this.disposable.dispose();` in `onSuccess` and/or `onError` (both? or just in `onSuccess`?), or will this class dispose by itself, as shown in the GitHub sample?

I'm asking this in the context of memory leaks.

This question has its roots in [RxAndroid `Observable...subscribe` highlighted in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59254710/rxandroid-observable-subscribe-highlighted-in-android-studio)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to dispose the disposable at there : `onSuccess`, `onError`.

Most operators have their own Observer. Each Observer is created and connected during Operator Chaining. After then, when you call `subscribe()`, disposable is created in the top-level DataSource Operator(e.g, `Single.just()`) and connected to the subscriber through the `ChildObserver.onSubscribe()` callback of each operator. Then, start with DataSource, check `Disposable.isDisposed()`, and call `ChildObserver.onSuccessful()` or `onError()` callback.

Anyway, Disposable is an interface to control the stream and does not hold resources statically. If your own logic works on the background and the result is applied to your view on the main thread, View components can be invalid if the Activity's life cycle goes through `onDestroy()`. So, it is general to call `dispose()` at there for this reason.